# GitHub Pages not building

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to publish an article to my blog on GitHub pages after a few months of absence, and am getting the following error:

> Gem::InstallError: public_suffix requires Ruby version >= 2.0.
>   Installing sass 3.4.20
>   An error occurred while installing public_suffix (1.5.2), and Bundler cannot
>   continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install public_suffix -v '1.5.2'` succeeds before bundling.

However according to GitHub the Ruby version on GH pages is already > 2.0. Is there some programmatic change that I need to make in my blog's codebase to get this up and running?

This is the corresponding Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# A simple Ruby Gem to bootstrap dependencies for setting up and
# maintaining a local Jekyll environment in sync with GitHub Pages
# https://github.com/github/pages-gem
gem 'github-pages'
```

Comment: Could you post your Gemfile from the directory you're running `jekyll` in?

Comment: Absolutely, there you go. There's also the `Gemfile.lock` but it's considerably longer so I'll only post it if that would help.

Comment: if you deleted your `Gemfile.lock` and pulled it down again from your repo on GitHub Pages before rebuilding, does this solve the issue?

Comment: @matrixanomaly that worked! Thanks :)

Comment: @LeviBotelho nice! i'll post an answer then :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try deleting your `gemfile.lock` and pull down the last working `gemfile.lock` file from your GitHub pages repo. (or just checkout the file from an earlier, working commit)**

Most of the weird errors stem from the errors with the `Gemfile.lock` file, which is used to keep track of the versions of each Ruby Gem. Sometimes when running `bundle update` gems are attempted to be upgraded, which may break compatibility with other gems, at least that's what has happened to me before. Often times running `bundle update` causes some gems to be downgraded. As a temporary workaround to just get Jekyll to build locally, just revert the file to an earlier version.